# Double Jump not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've written some code to control my player. The jump + jump animation(together with the dress and hair animations) plays when the character hits the space bar and when the player falls off of a platform.

My double jump is not working. My player can only jump once. Can anyone see why this isn't working?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class playerController : MonoBehaviour {
    private Animator anim;
    public Vector3 moveForward = new Vector3(1,0,0); 
    private float speed = 4;
    private bool isGrounded; 
    private Rigidbody rb;


    private bool doubleJump;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        doubleJump = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()  {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);


        if(isGrounded) {

            if(Input.GetKeyDown("space")) {
                if(isGrounded) 
                {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(10, 15, 0);
                anim.Play("rig|Character_ActionsJUMP", -1, 0f); 
                anim.Play("Dress_Armature |Jump", 1, 0f); 
                anim.Play("Hair_Armature|Jump", 0, 0f); 
                isGrounded = false;

                }

                else if (!isGrounded && doubleJump) {

                rb.velocity = new Vector3(10, 15, 0);
                anim.Play("rig|Character_ActionsJUMP", -1, 0f); 
                anim.Play("Dress_Armature |Jump", 1, 0f); 
                anim.Play("Hair_Armature|Jump", 0, 0f); 
                doubleJump = false;

                }
            }
            }
    } //endOFUpdate

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other) {
            if(other.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
            isGrounded = true;
            doubleJump = true;
            anim.Play("rig|Character_Run", -1, 0f );
            anim.Play("Dress_run", 1, 0f );
            anim.Play("Hair_Armature|run", 0, 0f );
            }
    }//endOfOnCollion

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision other) {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Ground") {
        isGrounded = false;

        }
        if(!isGrounded) {

        anim.Play("rig|Character_ActionsJUMP", -1, 0f); 
        anim.Play("Dress_Armature |Jump", 1, 0f); 
        anim.Play("Hair_Armature|Jump", 0, 0f); 
        }
        if(isGrounded) {
        anim.Play("rig|Character_Run", -1, 0f );
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the issue:

```
if(isGrounded) {

        if(Input.GetKeyDown("space")) {
            if(isGrounded) 
            {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(10, 15, 0);
            anim.Play("rig|Character_ActionsJUMP", -1, 0f); 
            anim.Play("Dress_Armature |Jump", 1, 0f); 
            anim.Play("Hair_Armature|Jump", 0, 0f); 
            isGrounded = false;
            }

            else if (!isGrounded && doubleJump) {

            rb.velocity = new Vector3(10, 15, 0);
            anim.Play("rig|Character_ActionsJUMP", -1, 0f); 
            anim.Play("Dress_Armature |Jump", 1, 0f); 
            anim.Play("Hair_Armature|Jump", 0, 0f); 
            doubleJump = false;

            }
        }
        }
```

In this code block you do not enter the check for Spacebar being pressed unless they are grounded, if we ignore the second check for them being grounded, your code becomes this

```
if(isGrounded) {

    if(Input.GetKeyDown("space")) {
        if (!isGrounded && doubleJump) {

            rb.velocity = new Vector3(10, 15, 0);
            anim.Play("rig|Character_ActionsJUMP", -1, 0f); 
            anim.Play("Dress_Armature |Jump", 1, 0f); 
            anim.Play("Hair_Armature|Jump", 0, 0f); 
            doubleJump = false;

            }
        }
        }
```

From this it is much easier to see the issue, the last if can never be fulfilled, as grounded has to be both true **and** false

So the solution is to remove your original if statement, as it is reduntant and in fact breaks the rest of the code!

As such, the code should really be as follows

```
void Update ()  {
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);

if(Input.GetKeyDown("space")) {
            if(isGrounded) 
            {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(10, 15, 0);
            anim.Play("rig|Character_ActionsJUMP", -1, 0f); 
            anim.Play("Dress_Armature |Jump", 1, 0f); 
            anim.Play("Hair_Armature|Jump", 0, 0f); 
            isGrounded = false;
            }

            else if (!isGrounded && doubleJump) {

            rb.velocity = new Vector3(10, 15, 0);
            anim.Play("rig|Character_ActionsJUMP", -1, 0f); 
            anim.Play("Dress_Armature |Jump", 1, 0f); 
            anim.Play("Hair_Armature|Jump", 0, 0f); 
            doubleJump = false;

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi I tried your code and it's not letting me jump at all now!

Comment: of course not, that code was an example, I can edit the actual code in if you would like, I was using the code there hypothetically!

Comment: Sorry i'm just a beginner. If you could edit the code it would be so helpful! Thanks so much :)

Comment: I'm a beginner too so no worries, the updated code is now at the end of the answer, this will replace the entire update method (includes the declaration) :)